# Java POI excel paging sheets

Tags: java, pagination, apache-poi

I'm working on a excel workbook, using **Java POI**.

I have several sheets and I need to add Pagination to **4** of them.
The problem is :

How I am suppose to attribute a global pagination to these sheets ?

`sheet.getFooter().setRight(HeaderFooter.page());` only works for ONE sheet.

Cordially.

Comment: If the need is printing multiple worksheets as one series of pages, then you must at first select **all** the worksheets that you want to print. After that the fields `&P` and `&N` in `HeaderFooter` will loop over all selected worksheets. See [Print one or several worksheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Print-a-worksheet-or-workbook-f4ad7962-b1d5-4eb9-a24f-0907f36c4b94).

Answer (score 1):

The Excel file format mandates that a footer is always per sheet, even in Excel itself you have to set up the footer for each sheet separately as far as I know. So the Apache POI API reflects this and you need to set the footer for each sheet.

Naturally you can write a helper function where you pass in the Sheet object to not have to code it 4 times here.